# Solr Character Tokenizer (split string into individual characters)

Tags: solr

Is there a Solr tokenizer that will separate a string by characters, e.g.

```
GD52KHC => G D 5 2 K H C
```

Comment: you can use EdgeNGramFilterFactory to achieve the same. To read more about tokenizers and filters... https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti, no, this is not possible

Comment: @Mysterion : check the below answer

Comment: this is not EdgeNGramFilterFactory :)

Comment: Mysterion is right, EdgeNGramand the regular NGramFilter are different. Edge only works from the start/end and will not produce fragments from the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the NGramFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer) for this with `minGramSize="1"` and `maxGramSize="1"`.

```xml
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" 
             minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="1" />
</analyzer>
```